# JavaScript Closure problem again!

Tags: javascript, closures

This is what i am facing with

```
function AAA(){
    this.f1 = function (){
        /*expecting that f2 will be call as both of then are of same object.*/
        console.log(f2(5));//
    }

    this.f2 = function(x){
        return x;
    }
}

x = new AAA();
x.f1(); //ReferenceError: f2 is not defined
```

Neither does it work,

```
function AAA(){
    this.f1 = function (){
        /*expecting that f2 will be call as both of then are of same object.*/
        console.log(f3(5));//
    }

    /*naming the function f3 hope to get function reference, as function 
     on the right side has name now and in the closure of f1, right?*/
    this.f2 = function f3(x){
        return x;
    }

    function f4() {};
}

x = new AAA();
x.f1(); //ReferenceError: f3 is not defined
```

What is happening here? who are in closure of 'f1' except 'f4'? can't we call the same object function without 'this'?

Answer (score 3):

You are not really using closures here. It will work fine if you change the line to

```
 console.log(this.f2(5));
```

If you want to use closures, you can rewrite the class as follows:

```
function AAA()
{
    var f1 = function()
    {
        console.log(f2(5));
    };

    // f2 is a private function.
    var f2 = function(x)
    {
        return x;
    };

    // Define the public interface.
    return { f1: f1 };
}
```

Comment: yes, I got your point but i wonder who are in closure of f1, or why can't we call same objects function without 'this'? what is the mechanism.

Comment: @abdullah829: In other languages you can omit "this" if you are referring to another member of the same object. You can't do that in javascript. If you just write "f2" and omit "this", then javascript will start looking for a local variable with this name, and then go up in the scope chain (closures) and finally it will look at the global scope (window object).

Comment: That's fine! thank you then, what does happen if you name a function like second example ... where name is f3, if you did not assign it to this.f2 it would work properly? right

Answer (score 2):

You’re confusing a few things here; `this` and closures are two completely different issues.

Your problem here is that you’re trying to refer to `f2` directly, thereby assuming that `this` is part of the current execution scope.  **It isn't**.
If you put `f2` on `this`, you’ll have to keep referencing it as `this.f2`.  To be able to reference `f2` directly, you’ll have to declare a (separate) variable by that name, which you can then assign to `this` if you want, as [qwertymk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025903/javascript-closure-problem-again#answer-5025948) says.

Personally, I try to avoid `this` as much as I can, since its meaning is completely dependent on how the function is called (e.g. if `AAA` is called without specifying the `new` operator, `this` will refer to the global object!).  It also saves you from headaches like the one above.  Closures (as demonstrated by [Elian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025903/javascript-closure-problem-again#answer-5025982)) are a much better way of obtaining this functionality.
Interestingly enough, I've found I hardly ever *need* to use `this`.

In Elian's example, `f2` is *closed over*: once the AAA function is done running, nobody can access f2, except the functions that were defined inside AAA (and are still accessible).  In this case, the function `f1` is accessible from the returned object, so that still exists.  Therefore, `f1` can still use `f2`.
That's what closures are about: a function can still access all the variables in its scope, even when those variables were declared in a function that's terminated.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `this.f2()` not `f2()` by itself. You would use `f2()` if it was a private variable which means if it was created with a `var` keyword.

```
function AAA(){
    var f3 = function(x) { return x; };
    this.f1 = function (){
        /*expecting that f2 will be call as both of then are of same object.*/
        console.log(this.f2(5));//
        console.log(f3(10));
    }

    this.f2 = function(x){
        return x;
    }
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L9bRL/1/)**

Comment: For exactly the reason qwertymk mentioned: The assignment to `this.f2` does not create a variable named `f2`, but your code tries to access a variable(!) named `f2`.

Comment: @Chistopher  What does happen with the second example, when I name the function as f3?

Answer (score 0):

Others have already told you what the problem is, so i will not repeat it. If you want your code to work, you just need a reference to this:

```
function AAA(){
    var self = this;
    this.f1 = function (){
        console.log(self.f2(5)); //self.f2 exists, yay
    }

    this.f2 = function(x){
        return x;
    }
}

x = new AAA();
x.f1(); //5
```